# How can i create this slightly bumpy wall?

Tags: materials

I want to create a material that looks just like this, how do i do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can mix a couple of layers of noise to produce a range of effects around the one you've posted.  Try this node group and mess around with the sliders.

[image]

Comment: i have copied the settings exactly but it still doesnt look like yours, how come mine looks more like crinkled paper than yours?

Comment: Mess with the noise scales until you get something you like.  It'll depend on the object.  Make sure your bump strength isn't too high.